# how to do exception handling in container managed JTA transaction

Tags: java, jta, apache-tomee

This is one part of my code. I am using JTA transaction and this piece of code is throwing unique constraint exception.

```
@TransactionAttribute( REQUIRED )
            private int createProfileHelper(AccountBean  accountInfo) throws Exception{    
        Long portfolio_customer_id = portfolioCustomerEntity.getId();
                            ExternalAccountEntity externalAccountEntity = new ExternalAccountEntity();
                            externalAccountEntity.setAccountNumber(accountInfo.getAccountNumber().toUpperCase());
                            externalAccountEntity.setBrand(brand);
                            externalAccountEntity.setAccountName(accountInfo.getAccountName());
                            externalAccountEntity.setRepId(accountInfo.getRepId());
                            externalAccountEntity.setCreatedBy(userName);
                            externalAccountEntity.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                            externalAccountEntity.setUserId(userId);
                            externalAccountEntity.setCustomerId(portfolio_customer_id); //join created between external account and portfolio_customer
                            persistenceToolsEntityManager.persist(externalAccountEntity);
    }
```

I wrote this code to handle exception:

```
public int createProfile(AccountBean  accountInfo){
        try{
            return createProfileHelper(accountInfo);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e);
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

To my amazement I am unable to catch exception in my try catch block though I can see the exception flashing on server :

```
Mar 13, 2015 9:19:58 AM org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl beforeCompletion
WARNING: Unexpected exception from beforeCompletion; transaction will roll back
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SEC.PORTFOLIO_EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_U1) violated
```

Comment: I think the exception is still caught, despite the transaction being rollbacked. Are you sure this is not the case?

Comment: Yes :( I put a breakpoint inside catch and I am unable to hit it

Answer (score 0):

It's not that amazing really.

Your `@TransactionAttribute( REQUIRED )` actually has no effect whatsoever. This annotation can only be applied to public methods, and only has an effect when called from a different bean. In other words, you cannot use annotations to demarcate transactions between method calls within the same bean.

The `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` has been trapped by the transaction manager upon exiting the `createProfile` method (which has an implicit @TransactionAttribute( REQUIRED ) by default).

Comment: Earlier I never created a private method. I just created it so that I can trap exception through my a public method having @TransactionAttribute( REQUIRED ). Anyways, how can I make my multiple db call as a single transaction ?...this public method is invoked by a rest call.

Comment: Catch the exception in the REST handler. i.e. The code that calls `createProfile`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a breakpoint on `persistenceToolsEntityManager.persist` and step into the code line by line.
You'll find that `org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl` handles the exception for you.
If you want to do something else when any exception occurs, try to use the `TransactionManager` and `getStatus()`.
:)